# for loop if variable exists - how pythonic can it be made?

Tags: python, coding-style

This is my situation:

```
for word in words:
    inferences = get_inference_list_for_word(word)
    # inferences can be []
    if inferences:
        for inference in inferences:
            #do something
    else:
        #handle empty inferences list
```

Is that a good way of going about it? Is there a better, pythonic way of writing the above code snippet? Maybe some functional wizardry or itertools magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating empty sequence is okay. So you can omit `if inference:`.

```
for word in words:
    inferences = get_inference_list_for_word(word)
    for inference in inferences:
        #do something
    if not inferences:
        #handle empty inferences list
```

Comment: +1 Looks cleaner! Thanks! Will wait for a while and accept if no one else comes up with some sorcery :)